# how to do LEFT JOIN in N1QL couchbase?

Tags: sql, database, couchbase, sql++

I am trying to do a simple LEFT JOIN of a table in couchbase. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.id,
  b.name
  FROM my_table AS a LEFT JOIN my_table AS b
  ON KEYS a.pid
  WHERE a.id='abc'
```

but for some reason the result I get is not including the fields of the table on the right side. Can anyone help me to achieve something similar to what we can do in relational database SQL as below?

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.id,
  b.name
  FROM my_table AS a LEFT JOIN my_table AS b
  ON a.pid=b.id
  WHERE a.id='abc'
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If nothing matched right side of JOIN projected as MISSING in (NOSQL) JSON vs NULL in SQL (i.e it gives LEFT side document extend right side as MISSING)

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  (CASE WHEN b IS MISSING THEN NULL ELSE b.id END) AS id,
  (CASE WHEN b IS MISSING THEN NULL ELSE b.name END) AS name
  FROM my_table AS a LEFT JOIN my_table AS b
  ON KEYS a.pid
  WHERE a.id='abc';
```

If the document b is matched and b.name is MISSING you still get MISSING. If you need null try this.

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  (CASE WHEN b.id IS MISSING THEN NULL ELSE b.id END) AS id,
  (CASE WHEN b.name IS MISSING THEN NULL ELSE b.name END) AS name
  FROM my_table AS a LEFT JOIN my_table AS b
  ON KEYS a.pid
  WHERE a.id='abc';

SELECT
 a.*, 
 IFMISSING(b.id,NULL) AS id, 
 IFMISSING(b.name,NULL) AS name 
 FROM my_table AS a LEFT JOIN my_table AS b 
 ON KEYS a.pid 
 WHERE a.id='abc';
```